# I want to backup a schema in remote Database as CSV file

Tags: postgresql, windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, database-backups

I have a **postgres DB** in linux server and I want to do a backup for certain schema every week. I create a batch script and add it to windows Task scheduler,but when I run it on my **Windows Server** it give me empty backup. here is my batch file :

```
@echo Backup database  %PG_PATH%%PG_FILENAME%
@echo off
SET PG_BIN='/usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin/pg_dump'
SET PG_HOST=XXXXX
SET PG_PORT=5432
SET PG_DATABASE=XXXXX
SET PG_USER=XXXXXX
SET PG_PASSWORD=XXXXXXX
SET PG_SCHEMA=XXXXX
SET PG_PATH=C:\
SET PG_FILENAME=%PG_PATH%\%PG_DATABASE%.csv
%PG_BIN% -h %PG_HOST% -p %PG_PORT% -U %PG_USER% %PG_DATABASE% > %PG_FILENAME%

@echo Backup Taken Complete %PG_PATH%%PG_FILENAME%
```

How can I fix this script to get csv file of schema backup?

Comment: you should use `-f` instead of `>`.

Comment: The first line cannot possibly output what you want, because it uses undefined variables. Also, if this is being run on Windows, do you really have a `pg_dump` executable file in a directory path `usr\lib\postgresql\11\bin` in the root directory of the drive of the current working directory, ```\```?

Comment: Also, in almost every issue when using Windows Task Scheduler, your question content should include **all** of the configuration settings for the scheduled task. This would confirm to us such things as which directory is the working directory for the running batch file, and any possible access and permission issues.

Comment: @Compo thank you for your reply , sorry this is the first time i write batch file , however, n i don't have pg_dump executable file in my windows. I assume that PG_BIN= where should the process start on in the remote server

Comment: No, your script, as I stated, is referencing a location which you have not defined within it, and is therefore relative to the root directory of whichever drive letter the current working directory is, at the time the script is run as a scheduled task. Also we still require **all** of your scheduled task configuration settings!